# WP7 + XNA game - online leaderboard

Tags: api, windows-phone-7, xna, leaderboard

Looking for online leaderboard for xna+wp7 game.

I was trying with www.mogade.com but they stopped supporting new users. Can anyone please let me know any other online leaderboard (free) available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this, seems good www.scoreoid.net

https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/featured/partners